# Web Audio API analyser node getByteFrequencyData returning blank array

Tags: javascript, audio, signal-processing, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to access FFT data from the analyser node using `analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array)` but it seems to return a blank array:

```
var array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
```

However using `analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(array)` returns an array of data:

```
var array = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(array);
```

I'm using a signal chain as follows:

`Source` -> `Analyser` -> `ScriptProcessor` -> `Context Destination`

So why can I not get frequency data in byte form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, my best guess is that you have the minDecibels and maxDecibels set to a range that is over the data you're pumping through the analyser, so it's getting zeroed out.

Comment: that'll do it. How do I know what value to set the minDecimals/maxDecimals? Thanks

Comment: OP: Was this actually the correct answer, as in, did you try adjusting the min/max Decibal values and it began working for you?

Comment: Also, for anyone, like me, stumbling upon this S/O question, here's a helpful link (http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/webaudio/AnalyserNode)

Comment: @fettereddingoskidney yes. Adjusting the min/max decibel values solved it.

Comment: What did you set the min and max decibel values to? I have tried -100, -30 & 0, 255. Array is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

What are the odds that one of you got the data before playback started, so there was nothing to read yet? If that might be the case, try to call `getByteFrequencyData` after playback is started.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `smoothingTimeConstant` is set to `1`. When it is so, `getFloatFrequencyData` always returns an array of zeroes.